# Modeling a line in 3D space using length and rotations rather than endpoints

Tags: vector-spaces, 3d, rotations

I'm using a cad software which can only create cylinders at the origin based on diameter `d` and height `h`. For simplicity sake, in this situation we can think of the cylinder as just a line so we can treat it as a vector. The orientation can only be changed by rotating it using `rotate([x,y,z])` which rotates a certain amount of degrees around each axis and can be translated using `translate([x,y,z])`. I'm trying to write a function that can take two 3D points `p1` and `p2` and automatically create a cylinder (line in our case) using `d` and `h` then rotate and translate it so that the endpoints rest on `p1` and `p2`.

It is easy enough for me to find the `h` of the line using the Pythagorean theorem, but the rotations are giving me a hard time. I used a bit of vector math I learned in a class a while back to find the angles from the line to each axis using unit vectors:
$p1 = (x_1, y_1, z_1) $

$p2 = (x_2, y_2, z_2)$

$\vec{F} = ((x_2-x_1) \hat{i} +(y_2-y_1)\hat{j} + (z_2-z_1)\hat{k})$

$\vec{u_F} = \frac{\vec{F}}{||\vec{F}||} = (\cos{\alpha} \hat{i} + \cos{\beta} \hat{j} + \cos{ \gamma} \hat{k})$

$\alpha = \arccos{\frac{x_2-x_1}{||\vec{F}||}}, \beta = \arccos{\frac{y_2-y_1}{||\vec{F}||}}, \gamma = \arccos{\frac{z_2-z_1}{||\vec{F}||}}$

This information is not the whole answer unfortunately. *The angle from the " "-axis* is not the same as *rotated around the " "-axis.* In addition, the order of the rotation changes the final result. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Are you using openSCAD? If so, there may be a considerably easier answer.

Comment: @JohnHughes yes I’m using openscad, please enlighten me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because OP is using OpenSCAD, the claims of the question aren't entirely correct: orientation can be changed not only by rotations about axes, but by other transformations as well.

I'm going to assume that the cylinder has been rotated/translated/whatever by the OP, who can surely do this, so that one end is at the origin, and the other end is at $(0,0,1)$. (Maybe OpenSCAD aligns it along $(0,1,0)$, but I don't think that adapting to this difference will present any challenges). I'm not going to write correct openSCAD code because I haven't used it in about a year, but I'll write something that should get you going in the right direction.

Here goes.

There's a `rotate(v, a)` function in openSCAD that rotates around a vector $v$ by angle $a$. We'll use that.

$$
\newcommand{zv}{\mathbf{\hat{z}}}
\newcommand{yv}{\mathbf{\hat{y}}}
\newcommand{sv}{\mathbf{{s}}}
$$

Let's let `zvec` (in code) or $\zv$ (in math) mean $[0,0,1]$, the initial axis of the cylinder. Then

1. Compute $v = Q - P$, the vector from the point $P$ to the point $Q$. If $v$ is zero, your input was bad (a length-zero cylinder makes no sense), and you'll have to handle this exceptional case.
2. Compute $u = \frac{v}{ \| v\|}$. In openSCAD, you do something like `v = (1/norm(v))*v`, I believe. If $u$ turns out to be exactly $-\zv$, then this is another special case; because the cylinder is already aligned with the $z$-axis, all you need to do is rotate it about the $x$-axis (for instance) by 180 degrees to get it where we want; you can then skip to step 5.)
3. Compute $w = \frac12 (\zv + u)$, or in code, `w = (0.5) * (u + zvec)`, and then $t = \frac{w}{\|w\|}$, or `t = (1/norm(w)) * w`. At this point, $t$ is a unit vector in the plane of $v$ and $\zv$, and is exactly halfway between those two vectors.
4. Rotate about $t$ by 180 degrees to take the cylinder, which used to point along the $\zv$ direction, and make it point along the $v$ direction instead.
5. Scale everything by $\| v \| $, i.e., `norm(v)`, which is the distance from $P$ to $Q$.
6. Translate by $P$ to move the origin (one end of the cylinder) to $P$, and the other end (which is at the tip of $v = Q - P$) to the point $Q$.

---

All of that stuff works mathematically, but I should caution you that the special case in step 2 is problematic: testing equality of floating-point numbers is fraught with peril. If the vector $u$ turns out to be very near to $-\zv$, then the remaining computations may be numerically a bit unstable, and you really don't want that. On the other hand, if you're just making a model of your back porch to decide where to put the picnic table, this nasty case is unlikely to affect you, and you can stop reading.

---

To continue: to make this whole approach a little more numerically robust, I'll modify things from step 2 onwards: if the vector $u$ is too close to being $\pm \zv$, I'm going to rotate the cylinder to point along the $y$-axis first. I'll use $\yv$ to denote the vector $(0, 1, 0)$. Here's the revised version, math only. I leave it to you to translate to openSCAD.

1. Compute $v = Q - P$, the vector from the point $P$ to the point $Q$. If $v$ is zero, your input was bad (a length-zero cylinder makes no sense), and you'll have to handle this exceptional case. In fact, if $\| v \|$ is smaller than, say, $10^{-5}$, you should probably treat this as an error case. (I can't recall whether openSCAD uses IEEE floats or IEEE doubles or something else to represent things, but using $10^{-5}$ as a threshold should keep you completely safe regardless. You could probably get away with using $10^{-10}$.)
2. Compute $u = \frac{v}{ \| v\|}$. If the absolute value of the $z$-component of $u$ is no more than $0.8$, let $\sv = \zv$; if the absolute value of the $z$-component is more than $0.8$, then rotate the cylinder by $-90$ degrees about the $x$-axis, so that it now lies along the positive $y$ axis, and let $\sv = \yv$. In both cases, $\sv$ refers to "the starting orientation of the cylinder".
3. Compute $w = \frac12 (\sv + u)$, and $t = \frac{w}{\|w\|}$,  At this point, $t$ is a unit vector in the plane of $v$ and $\sv$, and is exactly halfway between those two vectors.
4. Rotate about $t$ by 180 degrees to take the cylinder, which used to point along the $\sv$ direction, and make it point along the $v$ direction instead.
5. Scale everything by $d = \| v \| $, the distance from $P$ to $Q$. The cylinder now lies along the $PQ$ direction, with one end at the origin, and the other end $d$ units from the origin, i.e., it has the same length and orientation as the line segment $\overline{PQ}$.
6. Translate the cylinder by $P$ to move the origin (one end of the cylinder) to $P$, and the other end (which is at the tip of $v = Q - P$) to the point $Q$.

---

There's another method that involves constructing a $4 \times 4$ matrix directly, and using openSCAD's `multmatrix` operation, but it's probably a little messier to write and to understand, so unless you're unhappy with the solution above, I won't bother writing it out.

Comment: took a bit of playing around with, but I finally got it. Thank you for the detailed answer

Comment: I am adding an additional module that is a T-shape to the end of the cylinder. I would ideally like the t to always lie parallel to the x-y plane, but it has some arbitrary rotation based on the orientation of the cylinder. Do you have any insight on why or how to fix it?

Comment: Absolutely. But since that's a totally different question, you should ask it as a new question; that way the other answers here won't look stupid. NB: If $P$ and $Q$  both lie on the $z$-axis, there are infinitely many "correct" solutions, and you may not like the one you get. Perhaps your new question could ask "Given points $P$ and $Q$ and a vector $v$ orthogonal to some plane $H$, *but not parallel to $PQ$*, I need to make a cylinder aligned with the ray $PQ$, and another cylinder, crossing it at the top, whose axis is parallel to $H$ (i.e., orthogonal to $v$)."

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be rephrased as follows: Rotate the axis of the cylinder, represented by a vector (say $\mathbf{a}$) into another vector, say $\mathbf{b}$. It's easy to see that in principle one could do this by rotating on the plane formed by the two vectors by an angle given by:
$$\cos\theta=\frac{\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}}{||\mathbf{a}||~||\mathbf{b}||}$$

The axis of rotation is represented by the unit vector perpendicular to the plane which is the vector product of the two. It can be shown that:

$$\hat{\mathbf{n}}=\frac{\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}}{||\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b||}}$$

Armed with these expressions one can calculate the rotation matrix given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle). However, since the program uses only rotations along given axes, it's necessary to find angles such that the same job can be done by three subsequent rotations around the axes. Here I will assume that the x, y, z rotations are done in the order indicated.

Using the expressions for individual rotations around a particular axis, the net rotation matrix we get is:

$$R_z(\gamma)R_y(\beta)R_x(\alpha)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\gamma\cos\beta &-\cos\gamma\sin\beta\sin\alpha-\sin\gamma\cos\alpha&-\cos\gamma\sin\beta\cos\alpha+\sin\gamma\sin\alpha\\
\sin\gamma\cos\beta&-\sin\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma+\cos\alpha\cos\gamma&-\cos\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma-\sin\alpha\cos\gamma\\
\sin\beta&\sin\alpha\cos\beta&\cos\alpha\cos\beta
\end{pmatrix}$$

which when equated with the rotation matrix around the axis yields:

$$\sin\beta=n_zn_x(1-\cos\theta)-n_y\sin\theta\\\tan\gamma=\frac{n_yn_x(1-\cos\theta)+n_z\sin\theta}{\cos\theta+n_x^2(1-\cos\theta)}\\
\tan\alpha=\frac{n_yn_z(1-\cos\theta)+n_x\sin\theta}{\cos\theta+n_z^2(1-\cos\theta)}$$

Now one can readily solve for the three required angles, making sure that all possible solutions in the interval $[0,2\pi)$ are checked to match the known rotation matrix, which is easy with a computer available.

In the case of the problem stated above, vector $\mathbf{a}$ should be matched to the axis of the cylinder when created, and the vector $\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{p_1}-\mathbf{p_2}$.

Comment: What do the n, u and $\theta$ variables represent?

Comment: n, and $\theta$ are defined above. u is a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Start with your cylinder of radius $d$ and height $h.$
According to the OpenSCAD documentation, if you use the default value of **center**, that is, if it is **false**, you get a cylinder whose ends are circles with centers at $(0,0,0)$ and $(0,0,h)$.

Consider a vector between your two desired endpoints.
If you let $\vec p_1$ and $\vec p_2$ be the position vectors of the two endpoints,
then the vector you have defined is
$$\vec F = \vec p_2 - \vec p_1
= (x_2-x_1) \hat{\imath} +(y_2-y_1)\hat{\jmath} + (z_2-z_1)\hat{k}.$$
Let's find a rotation that turns the vector $h\hat k$ into $\vec F,$
that is, we want to rotate the vector that goes from the bottom to the top of the cylinder so that it points in the direction of $\vec F .$

One way to attack this is to work out $\vec F$ in spherical coordinates,
that is, find its angle of rotation $\phi$ away from the $z$ axis (its colatitude) and its angle of rotation $\theta$ around the $z$ axis (its longitude).

Mathematically, the colatitude is
$$ \phi = \arccos\left(\frac{z_2 - z_1}{\lVert \vec F \rVert} \right).$$
But if $\lvert z_2 - z_1\rvert$ is very close to $\lVert \vec F \rVert,$
the angle you get by this method is not very accurate.
There are various ways to work around this.
One way (based on the arctan formula on page 15 of [this paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/Cross.pdf)) is
$$
\phi = \mathrm{atan2} (\lVert \vec F - h\hat k\rVert, \lVert \vec F + h\hat k\rVert),
$$
where
\begin{align}
\lVert \vec F - h\hat k\rVert &= \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2 + (z_2-z_1-h)^2},\\
\lVert \vec F + h\hat k\rVert &= \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2 + (z_2-z_1+h)^2}.
\end{align}
and $\mathrm{atan2}$ is the usual two-argument arc tangent function.
(I omitted the step in Kahan's formula where each vector is divided by its magnitude;
since the magnitudes of the vectors are the same in this case, these factors cancel out anyway in the calculation of the arc tangent.)

For the longitude, you can take
$$
\theta = \mathrm{atan2}\left(\frac{y_2-y_1}{\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2}},
\frac{x_2-x_1}{\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2}}\right).
$$

Now to rotate the cylinder so it points in the right direction, you rotate by
$\phi$ around the $y$ axis and by $\theta$ around the $z$ axis.
Finally, translate by $\vec p_1$ to move the two ends of the cylinder to the desired points.

Note that since a cylinder is rotationally symmetric around its axis, you don't need three rotations around coordinate axes to orient it whichever way you want.
Two rotations is enough.

---

An alternative method is inspired by John Hughes' answer.
The idea is to rotate around a vector that is "midway" between $\vec F$ and the $z$ axis.
The vector $\vec F + h\hat k$ is one candidate, but it has an inaccuracy due to cancellation when the angle between the vectors is large.
So we make sure the angle between the vectors is *not* too large.

If $z_2 \geq z_1,$ then the angle between $\vec F$ and $h\hat k$ is a right angle or less. We can set
$$ \vec v =  h\hat k + \vec F, $$
rotate the cylinder by $\pi$ radians ($180$ degrees) around $\vec v,$
then translate by $\vec p_1$ so that the endpoints of the cylinder are where you want them.

If $z_2 < z_1$ then the angle between $\vec F$ and $h\hat k$ is greater than a right angle. We fix this by (in effect) reversing the direction of $\vec F$.
That is,  set
$$ \vec w =  h\hat k - \vec F, $$
and rotate the cylinder by $\pi$ radians  around $\vec w.$
This gives you a cylinder with one end at $(0,0,0),$ and the direction from there to the other end of the cylinder is the direction of $-\vec F,$ that is, the direction from $p_2$ to $p_1.$
The last step then is to translate by $\vec p_2$ (not $\vec p_1$) so that the end that is at $(0,0,0)$ moves to $p_2$ and the other end moves to $p_1.$